# Regular expression for Iranian mobile phone numbers?

Tags: c#, regex, validation

How can I validate mobile numbers with a regular expression?
Iran Mobile phones have numeral system like this:

```
091- --- ----
093[1-9] --- ----
```

Some examples for prefixes:

```
0913894----
0937405----
0935673---- 
0912112----
```

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Iran

Answer (score 25):

Best Regular Expression for Detect Iranian Mobile Phone Numbers

I'm sure its best regular expression for detect iranian mobile number.

```
(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}
```

---

#### use in javascript

```
var
mobileReg = /(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}/ig,
junkReg = /[^\d]/ig,
persinNum = [/۰/gi,/۱/gi,/۲/gi,/۳/gi,/۴/gi,/۵/gi,/۶/gi,/۷/gi,/۸/gi,/۹/gi],
num2en = function (str){
  for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
    str=str.replace(persinNum[i],i);
  }
  return str;
},
getMobiles = function(str){
  var mobiles = num2en(str+'').match(mobileReg) || [];
  mobiles.forEach(function(value,index,arr){
    arr[index]=value.replace(junkReg,'');
    arr[index][0]==='0' || (arr[index]='0'+arr[index]);
  });
  return mobiles;
};

// test
console.log(getMobiles("jafang 0 91 2 (123) 45-67 jafang or +۹۸ (۹۱۵) ۸۰ ۸۰ ۸۸۸"));
```

---

support all option like these

```
912 123 4567
912 1234 567
912-123-4567
912 (123) 4567
9 1 2 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
9 -1 (2 12))3 45-6 7
and all with +98 or 0
+989121234567
09121234567
9121234567
```

or even persian numbers

```
+۹۸ (۹۱۵) ۸۰ ۸۰ ۸۸۸
```

and only detect true iranian operator numbers 091x 092x 093x 094x

for more info : https://gist.github.com/AliMD/6439187

Comment: one (+) just for **jafang**

Comment: I think @Mostafa's answer is better. This method may be useful when you want to extract mobile numbers from some scraped text from the web, but when you're dealing with user input, no one is going to enter something that strange ( or jafang ;)

Comment: @nima its not work for persian number and +98** and +98 915 (123) *** and many others ...

Comment: I know and I've upvoted your answer. The point I was trying to make was that this method is not for everyone, and not everyone need this much complexity.

Comment: `([ ]|-|[()])` is better written `[- ()]`. `[1|2|3|4]` matches pipe character. Your regex matches [0--9|()1-(1-(1-(1-(1-(1-(1-(1-(](https://regex101.com/r/xl9ny9/1) not sure this is a valid phone number.

Comment: also can use this regex ```/^(\+?98|۰۹[\s]?|0)9|۹[0-99|۰-۹۹]\d[\s]?\d{3}[\s]?\d{4}$/```

Answer (score 9):

Simplicity is the beautify of life . Try this one  :

```
^09[0|1|2|3][0-9]{8}$
//091 for Hamrahe-Aval Operator
//092 for Rightel Operator
//093 | 090 for Irancel Oprator
```

Here is an Extension method in c# which I use regularly in my project :

```
public static bool IsValidMobileNumber(this string input)
{
    const string pattern = @"^09[0|1|2|3][0-9]{8}$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
    return reg.IsMatch(input);
}
```

Using like this :

```
If(!txtMobileNumber.Text.IsValidMobileNumber())
{
  throw new Exception("Mobile number is not in valid format !");
}
```

Comment: simplicity in this one is a joke :P  not working for 0903 too

Answer (score 6):

According to the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Iran#Mobile_phones, the matches are:

```
091x-xxx-xxxx
0931-xxx-xxxx
0932-xxx-xxxx
0933-xxx-xxxx
0934-xxx-xxxx
0935-xxx-xxxx
0936-xxx-xxxx
0937-xxx-xxxx
0938-xxx-xxxx
0939-xxx-xxxx
```

which looks like

```
(the specific sequence 09) (1 followed by 0-9 OR 3 followed by 1-9) (7 digits)
```

Assuming you dont care about the dashes for now, this translates to

```
09 (1 [0-9] | 3 [1-9]) [0-9]{7} <-- spaces added for emphasis
09(1[0-9]|3[1-9])[0-9]{7} <-- actual regex
```

(the `(..|..)` does OR, the `[0-9]{7}` says match exactly 7 digits, ...)

If you want dashes in the specified location:

```
09(1[0-9]|3[1-9])-?[0-9]{3}-?[0-9]{4}
```

should match

Answer (score 4):

How about this one ?

`^(\+98?)?{?(0?9[0-9]{9,9}}?)$`

working for:

09036565656

09151331685

09337829090

09136565655

09125151515

+989151671625

+9809152251148

[check out the results here](https://regex101.com/r/FGbSED/1)

Answer (score 3):

```
^(\+98|0)?9\d{9}$
```

Will match with numbers like +989123456789 and

```
^[0][9][0-9][0-9]{8,8}$
```

match with numbers like 09123456789

Answer (score 3):

the best **regex pattern**

> **(+?98|098|0|0098)?(9\d{9})**

Answer (score 3):

```
    const iranianMobilePattern = /^09\d{9}$/;

function isValidIranianMobile(mobileNumber) {
  return iranianMobilePattern.test(mobileNumber);
}
```

In this code, iranianMobilePattern is a regular expression that starts with ^ to indicate the beginning of the string, followed by 09 and \d{9} to match any 9 digits. Finally, the pattern ends with $ to indicate the end of the string.

The isValidIranianMobile function takes a string argument, which is the mobile number to check. It returns true if the mobile number matches the Iranian pattern, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

`^09\d{2}\s*?\d{3}\s*?\d{4}$`

This will also allow spaces between numbers (if they are 4-3-4).

Answer (score 2):

First of all lets write the reg ex for the numbers

`^09\d{9}$` which means it must start with 09 and followed by 9 digits

or instead of \d you can use ^09[0-9]{9}$
after that

```
Regex objNotNaturalPattern=new Regex("[^09[0-9]{9}]");
```

`objNotNaturalPattern.IsMatch(yourPhoneNumber);`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

in javascript you can use this code

```
let username = 09407422054
let checkMobile = username.match(/^0?9[0-9]{9}$/)
```

it will return

```
["9407422054", index: 0, input: "9407422054", groups: undefined]
```

Answer (score 1):

`\A09\d{9}` should do it for you

Answer (score 1):

Regex:

```
/^(\{?(09)([1-3]){2}-([0-9]){7,7}\}?)$/
```

Matches:

```
- 0913-1234567
- 0933-1234567
```

Doesn't match:

```
- 0944-1234567
- 0955-1234567
```

If you don't want the '-', simply remove it from the regex

Answer (score 1):

To support the 0903---- Irancell mobile numbers, use:

```
^(0|\+98)?([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}9[0|1|2|3|4]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,3}(?:[0-9]([ ]|,|-|[()]){0,2}){8}$
```

Comment: Why did you copy the [wrong previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618958/372239)?

Answer (score 1):

I used this for Iran Mobile and worked for Irancell , rightell and MCI 0935-0939 ,0912,0901,0910,0902,0903,...

```
 public static MobilePattern: string = '09[0-9]{9}$';
```

Comment: it shoudn't be this much simple.because numbers like 09000000000 are acceptable which is not a correct mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

```
string sPattern = "^09[-.\\s]?\\d{2}[-.\\s]?\\d{3}[-.\\s]?\\d{4}$";

if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(stringToMatch, sPattern)){
   System.Console.WriteLine("Phone Number is valid");
} else {
   System.Console.WriteLine("Phone Number is invalid");
}
```

The expression above will match any number starting with 09 followed by a space, dot, or dash if present, then 2 digits, etc

ex: 09001234567 or 09 11 123 4567 or 09-01-123-4567 or 09.01.123.4567 or 0900.000.0000 or 0900-000-0000 or 0900.000-0000 etc

Answer (score 0):

^09(1\d|3[1-9])-\d{3}-\d{4}$

is the regular expression that you need:

Starting with the beginning of the string (so no other digits sneak in)

09 is constant

1 can be combined with any subsequent digit, 3 cannot be combined with 0

-, and 3 digits

-, and 4 digits

End of string (again, so no other digits sneak in)

... but don't take my word for it, run it (I would recommend adding more test numbers):

```
        List<string> possible = new List<string> { "091-555-8888", 
"0915-888-4444", 
"0930-885-8844", 
"0955-888-8842" };

        string regex = @"09(1\d|3[1-9])-\d{3}-\d{4}$";

        foreach (string number in possible)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is{1} an Iranian number", number, Regex.IsMatch(number, regex) ? "" : " not");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple.
Iran TCI Phone in Any Format

Supports These Formats

+98217777777

98217777777

098217777777

0098217777777

217777777

0217777777

```
function IsIranPhone(phone) {
    if (phone == null || phone ==undifined) {
        return false;
    }
    return new RegExp("^((|0|98|098|0098|\\+98)[1-8][1-9][2-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$").test(phone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code in C#

```
  public bool IsMobileValid(string mobile)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mobile))
            return false;
        if (Regex.IsMatch(mobile, @"(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]) 
             {0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//check phone number
function check_phone(number) {
    var regex = new RegExp('^(\\+98|0)?9\\d{9}$');
    var result = regex.test(number);

    return result;
}

$('#PhoneInputId').focusout(function () {
    var number = $('#crt-phone').val();
    if (!check_phone(number)) {
       your massage...
    } else {
       your massage...
    }
});
```

> this is best answer, i tested all answers but this is easy and best