# ASP.NET MVC Attribute Not Functioning on Entire String Match

Tags: asp.net-mvc, regex, validation

Why is it when I specify against my ASP.NET MVC view model class the following definition:

```
     [StringLength(11)]
     [RegularExpression(@"‎^(09)[1-3][0-9]\d{7}$")]
     public string Mobile { get; set; }
```

this format is Mobile in Iran:

Start with: 09

A digit number between 1 and 3

7 digit between 0 and 9

---

But when I enter mobile number (for example 09124208640) `ModelState` isn't valid and get this error message :

```
The field Mobile must match the regular expression '‎^(09)[1-3][0-9]\\d{7}$'.
```

Comment: According to http://regexpal.com/ with the regex `^(09)[1-3][0-9]\d{7}$` and input `09124208640` it's a match.

Comment: @ta.speot.is can help me for create correct regex

Comment: I test in http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html and input is match.

Comment: Well your rules *Start with: 09 `2` ... A digit number between 1 and 3 `1` ... 7 digit between 0 and 9 `7`* is a string that's `10` characters long. Your regex asks something different, as does the `StringLength(11)` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
"‎^(09)[1-3][0-9]\d{7]$"
                    ^
```

Replace `]` with `}`.

Comment: I think the `[0-9]` part of `[0-9]\d` is redundant, no? Replace it with `\d{8}`??

Comment: @ta.speot.is, I agree with you. But you'd better comment to OP's question because the regular expression come from OP's code.

Comment: I'm not a regex guru. I was hoping someone that was could incorporate my feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7913002/242520), consider the following regex:

```
^09[1|3][0-9]{8}$
```

`[1|3]` matches `1`, `|` or `3`. This seems erroneous, leading us to:

```
^09[13][0-9]{8}$
```

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986651/asp-net-mvc-attribute-not-functioning-on-entire-string-match/17987047#comment26298026_17987047), if you need to accept `2` in the third digit:

```
^09[1-3][0-9]{8}$
```

Comment: tnx for help me,but this regex is't match and i have same error :(

Comment: `[13]` does not match `2`. BTW, OP did not used `[1|3]`.

Comment: @falsetru I know, [I'm working off what Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Iran#Mobile_phones). Iranian mobile phone numbers don't have `2` as their third character.

Comment: I use [1|3] and ModelState isn't valid and isn't match

Comment: @ta.speot.is, OP wants `A digit number between 1 and 3`.

Comment: @falsetru I know, but OP is trying to validate Iranian phone numbers.

Comment: Original Poster. [This guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1191018/hamid-reza-mansouri).

Comment: @falsetru new operator use 2 for example 09213552485

Comment: tnx,You are a great man , I test all above regex , and in all regex i have same error. I think there is a fundamental problem

Comment: @hamidrezamansouri Perhaps it is something elementary, like your textbox for `Mobile` being transposed with another textbox. E.g. `Mobile: <input type="text" name="address" />`