# php equivalent of C# regex for persian phone numbers

Tags: c#, php, regex, preg-match, cakephp-2.3

What is the equivalent Regex of this C# Regex expression in php:

```
(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}
```

It is regular express for persian mobile numbers brought from https://stackoverflow.com/a/18618958/1080355
Here is my code snippet in CakePHP validation rules:

```
    function isValidPhoneFormat($phone) {
    $phone_no = $phone['phone_number'];
    $reg_expression='(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}';
    $errors = array();
    if (empty($phone_no)) {
        $errors [] = "شماره وارد شده معتبر نمی باشد";
    //

    } else if (!preg_match($reg_expression, $phone_no)) {
        $errors [] = "شماره وارد شده معتبر نمی باشد";
    }

    if (!empty($errors))
        return implode("\n", $errors);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: It already looks platform-independent / portable... have you tried running it?

Comment: I don't know equivalent of ? in php

Comment: c# regex would work in php.

Comment: nope! leads to error: `preg_match(): Unknown modifier '?'`

Comment: just post your php code.

Comment: @VSB Surround it with `/` or something - it needs to be able to seperate modifiers from the match-code: `/(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}/`. `?` is equivalent in PHP, it just thinks that the code ends after the first `)`, because you start with an opening `(`, meaning that it will count `?` as a so-called modifier.

Comment: @AvinashRaj here is the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex works for me,

```
<?php
$mystring = "foo +98 91 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ";
$regex = '~(0|\+98)?([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}9[1|2|3|4]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}(?:[0-9]([ ]|-|[()]){0,2}){8}~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
+98 91 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: What are those ~ used for? Unfortunately i have not that much knowledge about regex!

Comment: @VSB `~` is a PHP regex delimiter. There are many regex delimiters in PHP.