# Flutter regular expression for validating mobile number

Tags: regex, flutter

i have written this regular expression to validating user mobile number but it doesn't work correctly.

```
String mobileNumber = '09328076432';
Pattern pattern = r'^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10}$';
RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
print(regex.hasMatch(mobileNumber));
```

validating all of character should be integer, length should be 11 character and starting with `09`

Comment: Your regex should be this `^+?09[0-9]{9}$`

Comment: Your regex is trying to match `09` followed by `10` digits, whereas you're willing to match a string which is `09` followed by `9` digits

Comment: What should be the length of digits after `09` ?

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761698/regular-expression-for-iranian-mobile-phone-numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is trying to match `09` followed by `10` digits, whereas you're willing to match a string which is `09` followed by `9` digits

So you can change your regex to this

```
^\+?09[0-9]{9}$
```

- `^` - Start of string
- `\+?` - Match `+` ( optional )
- `09` - Match literally `09`
- `[0-9]{9}` - Match any digits between 0 to 9, 9 times
- `$` -End of string

Answer (score 2):

Validation using Regex:

```
String validateMobile(String value) {
String pattern = r'(^(?:[+0]9)?[0-9]{10,12}$)';
RegExp regExp = new RegExp(pattern);
if (value.length == 0) {
     return 'Please enter mobile number';
}
else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
     return 'Please enter valid mobile number';
}
     return null;
}
```